# Сеть NAT в VirtualBox не дает выхода в интернет

Tags: virtualbox

Уже неделю бьюсь с настройкой сети в Virtualbox. Гостевая система - Ubuntu 20.04.3, Хост - восьмая версия Windows. В инструкциях пишут использовать сеть NAT для подключения гостевой ОС  к интернету. Но после выставления ее не удается выйти в сеть. Что может быть не так?

Comment: *Что может быть не так?* Да всё что угодно! для более осмысленного ответа недостаточно (точнее, их в принципе нет) данных - ни конфигурационных, ни диагностических.

Comment: В конфигурации сети для адаптера 1 и адаптера 2 в типах подключения выбран "Тип NAT". Версия Ubuntu x86-64. Имя сети "NetWork1", но она не активна.